# Instantiate calendar in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, custom-controls

I have a customized calendar in my xaml and now I want to create another instances of this calendar with that style in code. How can I instanciate or clone this customized calendar [xamlcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Qgw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something similar to this?

```
        var datePicker = new DatePicker();
        datePicker.Style = (Style)mainWindow.FindResource("DatePickerStyle");
```

Please use the appropriate type of control.

Also your style needs to be defined outside with a name

```
e.g. x:Key="DatePickerStyle"
```